# Split textarea content into two at maxlength and flow excedant content in another textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

Wondering if its possible to create a short simple and sweet cross-browser jQuery (1.6) function that would split `#textarea1` content into two by preserving the characters that amount to less than its `var maxlength` limit and transfering the remaining characters that exceed its `maxlength` limit in `#textarea2`. `#textarea1` edits **move** excedant in `#textarea2`, **and if user deletes some text in `#textarea1`, topmost content in `#textarea2` moves to bottom-end of `#textarea1`**. An optional param controller, **triggered via checkbox**, would only allow text flow from `#textarea1` to `#textarea2`. I am just beginning to scratch the surface of jQuery but I noticed that [this simple javascript can nearly do the trick](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=8091), minus the free-flowing character movement. The [jQuery Columnizer from Wulf](http://welcome.totheinter.net/2011/08/22/columnizer-jquery-plugin-update/) could also be a starting point, scratching my head on this one. Thx a heap for any help. DC

Answer (score 0):

OK, how about something like the following. Call `catchOverflow()` to setup a change handler on the specified fields, with specified maxChars; the overwrite param controls whether changes copied into the second textarea will overwrite what is already there or be added to the end.

```
function catchOverflow(f1Selector, f2Selector, maxChars, overwrite) {
   var f2 = $(f2Selector);
   $(f1Selector).change(function() {
      var val1 = this.value;          
      if (val1.length > maxChars) {
         f2.val( (overwrite ? "" : f2.val()) + val1.substr(maxChars) );
         this.value = val1.substr(0, maxChars);
      }
   });
}


catchOverflow("#textarea1", "#textarea2", 250, false);
```

**EDIT:** It's easy to add some more code to the above to test if the length of the first field is less than the maximum and if so copy `maxChars - val1.length` characters from the beginning of the second field. I'm sure you can figure that out for yourself based on what I've already given you.

[Clipboard events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html) don't work in Opera, which is why I just handled the `change` event in my original code above. But if you want you can also attempt to trap the clipboard stuff, and trap keyup and mouseup in the hope of getting all changes as they happen. In some browsers mouseup may catch drag and drop for you.

In the above code change this:

```
 $(f1Selector).change(function() {
```

to this:

```
 $(f1Selector).on("change keyup mouseup cut paste", function() {
```

Comment: Looking good! Trying to implement a cascading effect here with text flowing back and forth between two textareas, flow starts from textarea1 towards textarea2 and back again when text edits done in textarea1. A checkbox would modify the flow in a one-way manner: textarea2 would still get content from textarea1 but would not move content back to textarea1 following textarea1 content edits. Cut and paste with mouse must be available in textarea1. See modifications in Author Question for precise info. Thx alot for help!

Comment: I tried as best I could with the little that I know but your code gives an error. Also, the function has to respond after document load. I answered my question with some other code that fulfills my needs for now but which needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

The code below (jQuery 1.6.1) reflects my immediate needs but I want to change it so that when myLength exceeds 20, the excess text gets *moved in front* (no copy) of text contained in **mytextbox2**. At the moment, the code recreates a new textarea containing the excess text everytime contents in **mytextbox1** is past the limit, which i don't want. It has to create **mytextbox2** *only once*, and receive future excess text from **mytextbox1** in the manner mentioned above. Ofcourse in this example after a page refresh **mytextbox2** and its content are lost, such content is also never sent via a form, it just serves as a temporary placeholder for excess text:

```
$('#mytextbox1').live('keydown keyup mouseup cut paste', function(event) {
var myLength = $('#mytextbox1').val().length;

    if (myLength > 20) {
        var words = $(this).val().split(' ');
        var last_word = words.pop();
        var reduced = words.join(' ');
        $(this).val(reduced);
        $(this).css('height', '65px');
        $(this).after('<textarea id="mytextbox2"></textarea>');
        $(this).next().focus().val(last_word);
   }    
});
```

If the code can be made leaner and more valid for current major browsers be my guest and suggest your prouess. Should we still use the .live method? I'll leave this up to you to figure that one out for the purpose of this function. Thx alot for the help, it helps me flatten a bit the learning curve.

Comment: Tried `if (!$('#mytextbox2').is(':visible') && (myLength > 20)) {` with `}else {
   if ($('#mytextbox2').is(':visible') && (myLength > 10)) {` which triggers an alert but can't yet define some code that puts excess text from mytextbox1 to the front of text located in mytextbox2. I tried `$("#mytextbox2").text($("#mytextbox1").text());` nope; with `val` it erases mytextbox2 content and keeps it erased. I must be missing something so easy to implement huh? ;-(